# Send email without authentication

Tags: java, email, authentication, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to develop a code that allow to send mails with javamail without authentication.

```
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", 587);
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
        try {
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxxxxx@hotmail.com"));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    new InternetAddress("yyyyyyy@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
            message.setText("This is actual message");
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
        } catch (MessagingException mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But when i execute it i get this exception

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required.
```

Is it possible to send mails without authentication?? Am i missing something?

Comment: Not in 2014 using a public mail service, that's for sure. An SMTP server allowing sending mails without authentication is called an open relay and a source of spam.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", mailHost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

    session.setDebug(true);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromAddress));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toAddress));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setContent(body, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    message.setText(body);
    Transport.send(message);
```

Comment: You code need a password for the authentication but am looking for sending emails without authentication. I'm developing a contact form where the client can send an email without giving his password

Comment: He won't be able to do that using his own email address; you can send such mails from _another_ account which your app has access to.

Comment: This is not a good answer, since it has no explanation and it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail specifically does not support unauthorized mail sending. In fact most public SMTP servers don't (anymore) because this leads to way too much abuse.

You **may** be able to find a public smtp that does not require authentication but they are getting rare. You can always run your own smtp or simply...add authentication.

Especially if you are using gmail, you could simply pass in your credentials?